# Photoshop Layer -> SVG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, svg

I've got PSD file with vector logo (smart object). I need to save it as SVG for website use. I don't see such option directly in Photoshop though.

Can anyone shed some light on the process? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is probably File -> Export -> Paths to illustrator...

...and then in Illustrator File -> Save As... SVG.

This will also give you the opportunity to sanity check your paths before you export them. Illustrator is a much better option for editing vector artwork in any case.

Comment: exactly right, unfortunately Adobe doesn't make it easy to get SVG out of PS. But there's a free script you can use to export. check my answer for link

Answer (score 1):

There's a free PS script that lets you do this automatically. Just name the PS layers you want to export with'.svg' at the end and they will be converted to SVGs, keeping the colors. the file name will also be the name of the layer. http://hackingui.com/design/export-photoshop-layer-to-svg/

The script works with CS5, CS6 and CC

Comment: This script still requires Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LDC, but if you don't have Illustrator and do have Fireworks:

You could simply import it (or vectorize from scratch) into Fireworks — simply drag the PSD file with the smart object onto Fireworks — and then install [this script to export as SVG](http://fireworks.abeall.com/extensions/commands/Export/).

> Once you’ve downloaded and installed that plugin, create a new document containing just the vector you wish to export, select it and click Commands > Export > Export SVG

*Source: [Josh Emerson](http://joshemerson.co.uk/blog/using-svg-graphics-today/)*